# Special characters in GitHub markdown code blocks

Tags: github, markdown, special-characters

Markdown automatically escapes ampersands and angle brackets within a code block, so how is it possible to use special characters that require escaping for example: λ ?

I know that one solution is to edit the HTML output file, however my markdown is for a GitHub page and I don't have access to the generated file.

I use ReText and it allows me to insert a lambda directly in the editor and the preview shows it as well.  GitHub's view only shows a small "image missing" type of box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use HTML entities style to insert special characters. For example writing

```
&#955;
```

will produce a λ

See this Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for the complete reference.